# Create a web space for a Linux cluster (clueless!)

Tags: linux, website, https, cluster

Sorry for a lack of jargon knowledge and experience. I've recently become a very new sys admin for my research group's cluster in my graduate program. We have a server name

```
bar.foo.edu
```

with about 10 nodes named like

```
bar01.foo.edu
bar02.foo.edu
...
```

What is the process for creating access to something like

```
http://bar.foo.edu/
http://bar.foo.edu/~user/index.html
```

On another cluster it was as simple as creating `public_html/index.html` with permissions that allow access, but how do you execute this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe you could clarify your setup. What kind of clustering do you do? What clustering software in particular?

- Is the whole cluster for web serving (using load balancing, for example)?
- Do you use the cluster for scientific computations?

If it's the latter, then running a webserver on the cluster may be quite unrelated to the cluster setup. You could just run a regular webserver on one machine, then the clustering should be irrelevant. In that case womble's answer would be correct: Just configure Apache or some other webserver.

Just how to do this exactly depends on what you want to serve.

A final advice:

Why do you want to use a cluster as a web server? For various technical & administrative reasons it is usually considered preferrable to separate functions by machine. So if you already have a department webserver, student systems or similar, consider using these as the webserver; they might already be configured.

Comment: Yes, the cluster is supposed to be used for scientific computation, but no one besides me uses multiple machines at one time. I'm wondering this question because our research group lacks a representative webpage for ourselves and I hoped to hosted one at http://bar.foo.edu/

I was just wondering how to get started. Sounds like a separate machine to host is the way to go? Very low traffic, btw.

Comment: In principle a separate machine is best, but for a simple low-traffic website it's ok to host it on another system. Just follow womble's answer, and post another question if there is a more specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple installation of Apache on the machine that `bar.foo.edu` is pointing to will give you the latter, but I'm not sure what `bar01.foo.edu` and `bar02.foo.edu` have to do with that... I can't imagine that you really need a 10-node cluster to do some web serving, but if you do you've got a beyond-vertical learning curve ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably not enough space to lay out all the possible options, but here's a couple:

1. simple round robin'ing with bind & A records

   - bar.foo.edu has one page that 301
     redirects the user to slb.foo.edu
   - slb.foo.edu is listed in DNS with 10
     different A records that each point
     to a different server (bar01 - bar10)
   - Pros: very simple to setup; Cons:
     hard to manage the actual request
     path
2. linux-HA

   - http://www.linux-ha.org/
   - I've used it in the past for DNS and
     SMTP load balancing, worked pretty
     well
   - Pros: more configurable than #1,
     increased fault tolerance; Cons: more
     complicated to configure

Comment: Must have missed that part where I said "clueless", huh? =) Thanks for the keywords for me to google, though!